# Downloading files through filezilla creating extra spaces

Tags: php, filezilla

when I download certain files like PHP, html, jquery the downloaded file providing extra spaces in between the lines. I am using filezilla as my FTP client.

Is there a setting in Filezilla that would fix this problem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please go to the settings in filezilla.
There under transfers --> file type set the default transfer type to Binary. 
I think this will fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks prasanth prem. This works. The downloaded files don't have extra spaces now.

Comment: Works great. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 1):

In the top menu of FileZilla, set:

```
Transfer menu > Transfer type > binary
```